# Is a struct actually copied between goroutines if sent over a Golang channel?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

If a large struct is sent over a channel in Go, is it actually copied between goroutines?

For example, in the code below, will Go actually copy all largeStruct data between goroutines producer and consumer?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type largeStruct struct {
    buf [10000]int
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan largeStruct)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)
    go consumer(wg, ch)
    go producer(wg, ch)
    wg.Wait()
}

func producer(wg *sync.WaitGroup, output chan<- largeStruct) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("producer: %d\n", i)
        output <- largeStruct{}
    }
    close(output)
}

func consumer(wg *sync.WaitGroup, input <-chan largeStruct) {
    defer wg.Done()
    i := 0
LOOP:
    for {
        select {
        case _, ok := <-input:
            if !ok {
                break LOOP
            }
            fmt.Printf("consumer: %d\n", i)
            i++
        }
    }
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/fawEQnSDwB

Comment: Alternatively, if the struct contained a slice, `[]int', the effect of passing the slice (and therefore struct) by value would not copy the internal array. I'm not saying that is your answer however.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, everything is a copy in Go, you can easily work around that by changing the channel to use a pointer (aka `chan *largeStruct`).

// demo: http://play.golang.org/p/CANxwt8s2B

As you can see, the pointer to `v.buf` is different in each case, however if you change it to `chan *largeStruct`, the pointers will be the same.

@LucasJones provided a little easier to follow example: https://play.golang.org/p/-VFWCgOnh0

As @nos pointed out, there's a potential race if you modify the value in both goroutines after sending it.

Comment: Here's a playground demonstration of both types of channel: https://play.golang.org/p/-VFWCgOnh0

Comment: @LucasJones I'll add your example to the post for better visibility.

Comment: Just be aware of potential race conditions if you're sending a pointer only. You don't want to end up with both goroutines messing with the same struct

Answer (score 8):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Send statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements)
>
> A send statement sends a value on a channel. The channel expression
>   must be of channel type, the channel direction must permit  send
>   operations, and the type of the value to be sent must be assignable to
>   the channel's element type.

It's a copy because the value is sent to the channel by assignment to the channel's element type. If the value is a struct, then the struct is copied. If the value is a pointer to a struct, then the pointer to the struct is copied.